# MS-Word 文章 (.docx) 中、指定テキストが何ページ目にあるか調べたい

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, ms-word

Microsoft Word の docx 形式ファイルにおいて、指定したテキスト要素が何ページに表示されるのか、取得したいと考えています。

Apache POI または XML を直接操作した場合どうやって取得したらよいでしょうか。

そもそも不可能なのでしょうか。

Comment: 英語版のstackoverflowにも同じ質問が出てましたが、簡単には出来ない感じですかね… 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275165/how-to-get-the-line-number-page-number-of-a-particular-word-in-a-doc-docx-file

Comment: 思わぬ難問ですねこれ。できそうでできないもどかしさ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.xmlのページサイズ（w:pgSz）の高さからマージン（w:pgMar）のtop/bottom/header/footerを引いたものを変数で用意して、各パラグラフ（w:p）をドキュメントグリッド（w:docGrid）のlinePitchで乗算し、最初に用意した変数を超えたら改ページとするくらいしか浮かびませんね・・・。

例外として、各パラグラフの中にw:lastRenderedPageBreakもしくはw:brのw:type=pageがあればその場で改ページという条件が必要ですけれど。

ECMA-376でもページに関する記載は無いため、自力で上記のようにコンテンツ描画をエミュレートするしかなさそうです。

ただ注意してほしいのは、MS Officeは完全にECMA-376準拠というわけではないので、あらゆる例外が発生すると頭の片隅に残しておいてください。（私はExcelで泣きました・・・）